# Java What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java

```
class Ages {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int age = 3;
        Scanner agescan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello. Enter your age here: ");
        age = agescan.nextInt();
    }           
}
```

I'm trying to create something that says a certain thing depending on your age. I haven'y yet added the nested if and else stuff because this won't run.. WHY?

This is my error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Age Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Age at
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) at
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) at
    sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) at
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: yes exactly `this won't run.. WHY?` what does it say when you run

Comment: How are you trying to run it, and what error message do you get?

Comment: First of all, your code runs! It works as long as you enter a valid integer. May be you are giving it "3"  in your command line rather than 3. Or some other String which  rises exception.

Comment: This is my error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Age
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Age
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: The code you posted has a class named `Ages` while you are trying to run a class named `Age` (notice the missing s).

Comment: @RogerLindsjö thanks. i remember changing that thinking it would change the class name as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not have any errors. I ran it. Have you pressed Enter after entering the age?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ages {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int age = 3;
        Scanner agescan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello. Enter your age here: ");
        age = agescan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You entered: " + age);
    }

}
```

Comment: No issue with the code that I can see, and when run it's okay. Would be nice if the OP would state what the error was.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. This is the error message i get: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Age
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Age
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: One  of the issues might be that your code is not compiled when you try to run it or something wrong with the classpath used at runtime

Comment: @user2634251 then the problem is not in the code you've posted. Until you post the real code that's giving you problems, there's no exact answer to your question.